# How to encode symbols "<" and ">" in Perl/XML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I am using Perl to create an XML file and then using

```
use XML::LibXML;
```

In one part of code I need to write some explanation in one node by

```
$writer->characters("<![CDATA[$xmlFile]]>");
```

What I have as an output is

```
&lt;![CDATA[example.xml]]&gt;
```

But what expect to have would be

```
<![CDATA[example.xml]]>
```

I have checked `&lt;` and `&gt;`, but it does not work at all. Because istead of symbol `&` again it prints out encoding, too.

Does anyone have an idea how to come over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to use `characters` to write a CDATA section directly; it generates *text*, not elements and not special constructs like CDATA sections, PIs, or comments. Instead (assuming `$writer` is an `XML::Writer`) you can do `$writer->cdata($xmlFile)`.

Comment: @Royeh well, you never said anything about `XML::Writer` before now, so I had no way to guess that's what you were using. Updated to match its interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!!